# How can I add view to ViewGroup in ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewgroup

```
@Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View pager, int position) {

    ViewGroup view = new ViewGroup(mContext) {
        @Override
        protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        }
    };
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

    View view2 = new View(mContext);
    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(200, 200);
    view2.setLayoutParams(lp);
    view2.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

    view.addView(view2);

    ((ViewPager)pager).addView(view, 0);
    return view;
}
```

Is it possible?
If not, how can I add a ViewGroup to a ViewPager?

Please, help me out.

Comment: Maybe you can use relativelayout instead of Viewgroup.

Comment: No.. it didn't run... I tried other way. But why it doesn't run..

Comment: Why do you want to add a `ViewGroup` to a `ViewPager`?  Please state your purpose, maybe we can find another way out.

Comment: I want to add ViewGroup to ViewPager on java code. and I also want to add some views to the ViewGroup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use FragmentPagerAdapter to add fragment to ViewPager.
Fragments can contain any viewgroups.

Comment: Yap! This is another way! But is my question impossible?

Comment: I could not find the way.  ( use shadow viewgroup and cunstum view which render hided viewgrop content? its not good )

Comment: Oh I see. I was just trying! Thank you for answer!